# VBA direct access to ribbon element values

Tags: vba, excel, ribbonx

How can I access to my custom ribbon elements?

The elements are made in (.xlsm\customUI\customUI.xml)

```
<ribbon startFromScratch="false">
    <tabs>
        <tab idMso="TabHome">
            <group id="MatrixGroup" label="xxx" insertBeforeMso="GroupClipboard">
                <button id="b1" label="111" imageMso="DataFormSource" onAction="asas" />
                <button id="b2" label="222" imageMso="ConditionalFormattingClearMenu" onAction="sasa" />
                <dropDown id="Drop" label=" Env" sizeString="WWWWWWWWW">
                    <item id="Item1" label="1"/>
                    <item id="Item2" label="2"/>
                    <item id="Item3" label="3"/>            
                    <item id="Item4" label="4"/>
                </dropDown>
            </group>
        </tab>
    </tabs>
</ribbon>
```

I need to get chosen dropDown element name/id when I click by button id="b1" so onAction="myMacro" for the dropDown element can not help here.

But anyway there is a code to get dropdown element id - maybe you can transform it to call this sub from another Sub (which is triggered by pressing button id="b1")

```
Sub GetS(control As IRibbonControl, id As String, index As Integer)
    If control.id = "Drop" Then
    MsgBox id
End If End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several callbacks you might use in this case:

1. `GetSelectedItemIndex`: I think this returns the index position of the Selected Item from Dropdown control.
2. `GetItemLabel`: Returns the selected item label from a ribbon dropdown control
3. `GetItemID`: Returns the ID of the specified `Index` item

The signatures for each are:

```
Sub GetSelectedItemIndex(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)

End Sub

Sub GetItemLabel(control As IRibbonControl, Index As Integer, ByRef returnedVal)

End Sub

Sub GetItemID(control As IRibbonControl, Index As Integer, ByRef id)

End Sub
```

You're correct that you can pass a `control` object from one callback to another (essentially manually invoking/triggering the callback procedure for these).

I'm not in any position to test this, so I'm going a bit from memory and a bit from guesswork, you may need to tweak this and debug on your own, but hopefully this is helpful. The way thiswould need to work, if I remember correctly, is when the `sasa` callback is invoked, you need to manually call `GetSelectedItemIndex` and then `GetItemLabel`, passing the appropriate `control` object.

**That's the tricky part, keeping a handle on the dropDown `control` object.**

Practically speaking, there is some difficulty with Ribbon object, and I found it was more easy to work with by loading it initially into a custom class object (retaining direct object references to each of the controls in a `Dictionary` property, keyed by control name/id) so that I could pass them at will from other procedures). There is some background on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154573/powerpoint-add-in-loss-of-ribbonui) which might be enough to go on, in terms of setting up the Class object, you'll just need to add another property `Get` and `Let` procedure as a `Dictionary` type so you can add each ribbon control to the dict. If you have trouble with that implementation, please ask a separate question on that and I'll try to help.

So, once you can access the appropriate control, you pass that object to the `GetSelectedItemIndex` e.g.:

```
Dim ctrl as IRibbonControl
Dim itm_id, itm_index 
Set ctrl = {some object reference to the dropDown control}

Call GetSelectedItemIndex(ctrl, itm_index)
Call GetItemId(ctrl, itm_index, itm_id)
MsgBox(itm_id)
```